# Nested loop over the elements of the same array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, iteration, nested-loops, mask

I have a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I would like to iterate over each element and compute a statistic using all the elements except the one at the current index. Statistic would require looping over each element.

```
stats = np.array([])
for ind1,x in enumerate(a):
     s = 0
     for ind2,y in enumerate(a):
           if ind2 != ind1:
                s = s + compute_stat(y)
     stats[ind1] = s
```

It looks like I might mask the current index, however, I would then need to reset the mask within each loop.

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.ma.array(a)
for ind1,x in enumerate(a):
     a[ind1] = np.ma.masked
```

What is the best way to use a nested loop in this case to iterate a computation over (n-1) elements of the same array?

Thank you